how i can truncate before sinking the data in that table in cdap studio
I am using cdap studio and i want to truncate the same table sinking data in table vai cdap studio.
how i can truncate table before sinking data in table
Is there any plugin vaiable that can be used for the same

It depends on the sink plugin used in the cloud data fusion pipeline.
For example,

If we are writing the data in BigQuery, the BigQuery Sink plugin supports a config to truncate table.
If we are writing the data to some on-prem DB, we can use DB Action Plugin which can run before pipeline source starts to read data and truncate the destination table.

